# Find match between ID and Class

Tags: jquery, html, class

I'm stuck here.. Trying to show a div with the class name that matches the id of the checked input element.

This is what I got so far, what's going wrong?..

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="one" name="choice" checked />
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="two"/>
<div class="one">
    Hello!
</div>
<div class="two">
    Goodbye!
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input').click(function(){

    var currentElement = $(this).parent().find('input:checked').id;

    $(document).getElementsByClassName(currenElement).show();

});
```

CSS:

```
div{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not a jQuery method and you'd have better to use onchange event and `id` is a DOM node property. You are mixing all it up

Comment: Thanks, know now what went wrong!

Comment: No idea why people are downvoting this post.. It's one of the better questions considering the tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `id` in jQuery objects. To get the id of an element, you need `attr('id')`:

```
var currentElementId = $(this).parent().find('input:checked').attr('id');
```

However, the whole thing can be done without mixing JS and jQuery:

```
$('.' + currentElementId).show();
```

So, assuming there are no mistakes in your approach - We're taking the ID of a checked input element and then looking for the elements with the class name that is the same as the id we just fetched, and then show all the elements with that class.

Here is your working example: http://jsfiddle.net/N8yVt/1/

(note that I've added a hide function, so that you either see Hello or Goodbye)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing jquery with javascript -

try this -

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().find('input:checked').attr('id');
    $('.' + id).show()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//use change event
$('input').change(function () {
    //hide all other inputs other than the target one
    $('div').hide().filter('.' + this.id).show()
}).filter(':checked').change(); //to initialize the initial display
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9L5jb/)

Comment: Works fine except for one thing, the 'this' isn't this in the larger picture. I use a link to trigger it. Should I make a variable instead of this?